# StyleCop by Resharper Plugin - How to enable only for 1 solution

Tags: resharper, stylecop

We have a VS solution which has StyleCop configured.

Because I do use ReSharper I wanted my scaffolding to work alongside stylecop. Fortunately there is a plugin named "StyleCop by Resharper Plugin".

After installing "StyleCop by Resharper Plugin" every VS solution that I open will be proofchecked according to "some" stylecop rules.

For me this is confusing as only one solution has Stylecop.settings file, and the analyzers package installed.

#### How to make stylecop proofcheck only the configured solution.

P.S. I don't want to include ignores in all my solutions because of one project using stylecop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 then you could use the [StyleCop.Analyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers) NuGet package that will use the Roslyn analyzers. This can then be applied per project.